How to add twitter and website handles to SPL Tokens, to show up in Solscan
I have created a Spl token with metadata using the Token Program and createCreateMetadataAccountV3, the matadata file contains reference to social media handles defined in extensions e.g.
    "name": "TEST",
    "symbol": "TEST",
    "description": "TEST",
    "image": "https://arweave.net/123",    
    "extensions": {
        "website": "https://google.com/",
        "twitter": "https://twitter.com/something",
    },

However when I view the token in Solscan, the social media handles are not displayed. Here is the token address on Solana Devnet - 4UsLvC3ajjmPyzna6tJeFxgCumQQRsJihThqNyaET5Lx
What is the suggested approach to do this?
Thanks

I've investigated the issue regarding your token metadata not displaying as expected on Solscan, specifically focusing on the extensions you mentioned for social media handles. After checking the metadata for your token on Solscan it appears that Solscan is correctly fetching the metadata from the URI you have specified.
I am led to believe that this is not displaying due to your Token being on Devnet itself.
https://solscan.io/token/4UsLvC3ajjmPyzna6tJeFxgCumQQRsJihThqNyaET5Lx#metadata
{6 items
name:
"Blockchain Wizard's Token"
symbol:
"BWT"
description:
"BlockChain Wizard's Token"
image:
"https://arweave.net/eNsOyYW1Gp8o6TNvTOqM-kQgI45rWxciw_oAW2DYywk"
extensions:{3 items
website:
"https://elcato.vip/"
twitter:
"https://twitter.com/ElCatoSOL"
telegram:
"https://t.me/ElCato_Portal"
}
tags:[2 items
0:
"Meme"
1:
"NFT"
]
}

For comparison, here's a similar metadata entry from a token on the Mainnet:
{7 items
name:
"MANEKI"
symbol:
"MANEKI"
image:
"https://i.ibb.co/Jnz56gp/Maneki-PFP.png"
description:
""
extensions:{3 items
website:
"https://manekineko.world"
twitter:
"https://x.com/UnrevealedXYZ"
telegram:
"https://t.me/maneki_official"
}
tags:[2 items
0:
"Meme"
1:
"cat"
]
creator:{2 items
name:
"ABC"
site:
"https://x.com"
}
}

As observed, the structure and presentation of metadata for both Devnet and Mainnet tokens appear consistent. It's crucial to consider whether extended metadata (like social media handles) is consistently shown across different networks such as Mainnet/Devnet
Have you encountered other tokens on Devnet within Solscan that display the extended metadata (e.g., social media links) you are attempting to include?

Hi Chris, I tried the same token on mainnet - but it still not showing the socials. token - https://solscan.io/token/A5nxUN8TbTozDC1Uogmx5jYoX9kpvanVE6ZCtGSYuKCw#metadata . I am not sure if any other tokens on devnet shows the social info on solscan, but on mainnet - many tokens display the socials including cmc, cg.

@BlockLearner to display cmc, price and others would you not need to list on a DEX first? I am confirming with SolScans team to verify if social handles are displayed upon DEX listing being completed

Ok so yeah it won't display for tokens on Devnet and to display for your token on Mainnet you have to submit your token to CoingGecko (CG) @BlockLearner

bobby | Admin WON'T DM U — 04/08/2024 12:41 AM
please submit your token to coingecko
WiseUp2RiseUp — 04/08/2024 2:58 AM
So we can no longer use metadata to have the socials on the mint address? Sounds like you’re forcing people to be listed on CG first?
bobby | Admin WON'T DM U — 04/08/2024 5:21 AM
We only recommend the projects to do that because in order to display the token's socials on Solscan, the token will have to be certified as "Neutral" or "OK" for the datat to be displayed as it will ensure the credibility of those links. We humbly as for your understanding
-Discord

Thanks Chris, that clears it up. Thanks for following up with solscan. Much appreciated.

Np :) @BlockLearner, if this was helpful please mark as correct technically answered your first question with Devnet tokens not being able to show such info as well as going above and beyond to get that info for listing on Mainnet :)

I just did. Hope that's the correct way to mark an anser.

@BlockLearner yeaup :), ty :)
